# Domain and range of a square root

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I got a question given by my lecturer to find the domain and range of this function:
$$y=\sqrt{2-x^2}$$

For the domain, we start by restricting the square root to be non-negative. After factorising, it becomes $(x+\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2)\le0$. This is my explanation.

But the lecturer at this point jumps to the conclusion that $y:[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]\mapsto[0,2]$ without any explanation.

I tried to substitute 2 as the value of y but it is wrong. Can anyone care to explain how he derived the domain from the factorisation and range?

Answer (score 1):

The correct factorization is

$2-x^2=(\sqrt{2}+x)(\sqrt{2}-x)$

where the left factor is nonnegative for $x\geq-\sqrt{2}$
and the right factor is nonnegative for $x\leq\sqrt{2}$.
Thus the function is defined on $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$.
The factors can´t be both negative since the conditions $x<-\sqrt{2}$
and $\sqrt{2}<x$ exclude each other. Thus $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ is the maximal set of real numbers where the function is defined.
Obviously the minimal value $0$ is taken for $x\in \{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$ and because of the monotonicity of the squareroot the maximal value is taken when the radicand is maximal thus for $x=0$ and this maximal value is $\sqrt{2}$. Thus the mapping is a mapping $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]\rightarrow [0,\sqrt{2}]$ The image of $f$ is  $Im(f)=[0,\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: I'm still confused with how range is being identified. Isn't it found by just subbing the individual highest / lowest domain into the equation to find the range (y)?

Comment: I'm a little confused over the fact that `radicand is maximal thus for x=0`. Isn't the maximum value of the domain(x) is `√2` like how it is in the domain  [−√2, √2]?

Comment: The minimum is $0$ since the square root is non-negative and the maximum is taken for the maximal value of the radicand because of the monotonicity of the square root and $2-x^2$ is maximal for $x=0$ The maximum that is taken is $\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

Your lecturer appears to have made a typo.

it should have been $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow [0,\sqrt{2}]$

You have made the correct start by saying that the square root must be non-negative. Using that information you can then change your equation from this:
$$y = \sqrt{2-x^2}$$
to this:
$$2-x^2 \geq0$$

a bit of rearranging and out pops the domain limits.
$$2 \geq x^2$$

$$-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$$

so from this we can see the domain limits are $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$

Then to get the upper bound on the range, maximise the radicand (the part under the square root). $x=0 \rightarrow y=\sqrt{2}$

So you end up with $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow [0,\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: I'm still confused with how range is being identified. Isn't it found by just subbing the individual highest / lowest domain into the equation to find the range (y)?

Comment: I'm curious how does maximizing  the radicand (the part under the square root) gives `x = 0`. However, the maximum value of the domain is `√2`

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan It may help to look at a graph of it.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(2-x%5E2),+x%3D-sqrt(2)+to+x%3Dsqrt(2)

It isn't necessarily the limits of the domain that create the limiting values of the range.

You basically set yourself a challenge. Find the maximum value you can create by varying x (the upper limit) and find the lowest value you can make (lower limit)

Comment: To find the upper limit of $\sqrt(2-x^2)$ you need to make $2-x^2$ as **big** as possible, and so $x$ as **small** as possible. Making $x$ as small as possible within your domain is the same as saying $x=0$

To find the lower limit of $\sqrt(2-x^2)$ you need to make $2-x^2$ as **small** as possible, and so $x$ as **big** as possible. This is the same as taking either limit of your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, it's much simpler to use absolute values:
$$2-x^2\ge 0\iff x^2\le 2\iff \sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert\le\sqrt 2\iff -\sqrt 2\le x\le\sqrt2.$$